# While implementing react-intl-tel-input in my react JS it give me errors

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, jsx, web-deployment

Hello I have started learning ReactJS and from last 1 week i stuck with a problem. I am using React with Firebase Phone Authentication. I want to use react-intl-tel-input for taking Phone input. I have installed the npm package and write the code as told in documentation. after running the code it takes the input correctly but after clicking on verify it say this number is not register but this number work perfectly with  tag but not with this

please have a look on my code

```js
import React from 'react'
import firebase from './firebase'
import 'firebase/auth';
import "./App.css";
import { getDatabase, ref, child, get } from "firebase/database";
import IntlTelInput from 'react-intl-tel-input';
import 'react-intl-tel-input/dist/main.css';


class Login extends React.Component {

  state = {};

  handlePhoneChange = (status, phoneNumber, country) => {
    console.log({ phoneNumber });
    this.setState({ phoneNumber });
  };

  handleChange = (e) => {
    console.log (e)
    const { name, value } = e.target
    this.setState({
      [name]: value
     
    })
    console.log (value)
    this.setState({ phoneNumber: value }, () => {
      console.log(this.state.phoneNumber);
    });
  }
  configureCaptcha = () =>{
    window.recaptchaVerifier = new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier('sign-in-button', {
      'size': 'invisible',
      'callback': (response) => {

        // reCAPTCHA solved, allow signInWithPhoneNumber.

        this.onSignInSubmit();
        console.log("Recaptca varified")
      },
      //  defaultCountry: "IN"
     }
    );
  }
  onSignInSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    this.configureCaptcha()
    const phoneNumber = this.state.mobile
    console.log(phoneNumber)
    const appVerifier = window.recaptchaVerifier;
    const dbRef = ref(getDatabase());
    get(child(dbRef, `Users/${phoneNumber}`)).then((snapshot) => {
      if (snapshot.exists()) {
        firebase.auth().signInWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumber, appVerifier)

          .then((confirmationResult) => {

            window.confirmationResult = confirmationResult;

            alert('An OTP has been sent to your registered mobile number')
            localStorage.setItem("Phone_No", phoneNumber)
            console.log(localStorage.getItem('Phone_No'));

          }).catch((error) => {

            console.error(error);
            alert("Oops! Some error occured. Please try again.")
          });
      }
      else {
        alert('Sorry, this mobile number is not registered with us. Please use your registered mobile number.');
      }

    })
  }
  onSubmitOTP = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const code = this.state.otp
    console.log(code)
    window.confirmationResult.confirm(code).then((result) => {
      // User signed in successfully.
      const Users = result.user;
      console.log(JSON.stringify(Users))
      this.props.history.push("/home");
    }).catch((error) => {
      alert("You have entered wrong code")
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
      <main>
        <div className="img">
          <img src="./55k-logo.png" alt="Company Logo" style={{ height: "80px", width: "200px" }} />
          <br />
        </div>
        <fieldset>

          <div className="Main-header">
            <h1>Sign-In</h1>
            <p>Limtless Water. From Unlimited Air.</p>
            <form onSubmit={this.onSignInSubmit}>
              <div id="sign-in-button"></div>

               <label>Mobile Number</label> <br />  
               <IntlTelInput
              containerClassName="intl-tel-input"
              inputClassName="form-control"
              name="mobile"
              placeholder="Enter Your Number"
              input
              type="tel"
              value={this.state.phoneNumber}
              onPhoneNumberChange={this.handlePhoneChange}
            />

             {/* <input type="tel" id="phone" name="mobile" placeholder="Enter Your Number" required onChange={this.handleChange} /> */}
              <div className="buttons">
                <button type="submit">Verify</button>
              </div>
            </form>


            <div>
              <form onSubmit={this.onSubmitOTP}>
                <label >Code</label> <br />
               <input type="text" name="otp" placeholder="Enter six digit code" required onChange={this.handleChange} />
                <div className="buttons" >
                  <button type="submit">Continue</button>
                </div>

              </form>

            </div>

          </div>

        </fieldset>
      </main>
    </>
    )
  }
}
export default Login;
```

after running the code i got this message but my number is registered

But my code work perfectly with this
`<input type="tel" id="phone" name="mobile" placeholder="Enter Your Number" required onChange={this.handleChange} />`  but i don't want to take input with normal input tag because here user have to type country code manually

Comment: This looks like the same issue you had on a previous question with `this.state.phoneNumber` not working. You need to provide an initial state. `state = {}` was sufficient to resolve the `phoneNumber` issue in your other question's codesandbox. And remember, the `IntlTelInput` didn't seem to use the `onChange` handler, it used an `onPhoneChange` handler and isn't passed an `onChange` event.

Comment: @DrewReese sir please have a look i updated my code as you say but after clicking on verify it say this number is not register but this number work perfectly with <input> tag but not with this i updated my code and attached the error message please have a look

Comment: Because the `onPhoneChange` handler passes different arguments you'll need to create a new/different handler to specifically set a `this.state.mobile` state value so it's defined. Codesandbox seems to be having some issues right now, when I get back in to the one from your other question I'll check.

Comment: Ok Thank you @Drew for your help

Comment: Ok, so I just [forked the CSB](https://codesandbox.io/s/how-to-integrate-react-intl-tel-input-forked-m9biv?file=/src/App.js) from my answer to your last question, and switched from `this.state.mobile` in the submit handler to `this.state.phoneNumber`, and the submit handler sees the state correctly. And sorry, the correct handler is `onPhoneNumberChange`, not `onPhoneChange` as I had stated earlier. Take note of the args passed to the new `handlePhoneChange` handler: `status`, `phoneNumber`, and `country`.

Comment: @DrewReese Can i take number in e.164 format??